# Applying layer file not formating labels in ARCGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arctoolbox, layers

I'm applying layer files in ARCGIS 10 using the ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management command via a python script tool.  The symbology part works fine but the lables are not formatting.

It is my understanding that applying a layer file should also format the lables as well.  Has anyone else had this issue?  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is the code I am using.

---

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

## Create parameters for modelbuilder user specified fields.
symbolize_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)
symbol_lyrFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)


arcpy.AddMessage("**** Step 1 ****")
#  apply symbology
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (symbolize_layer, symbol_lyrFile)

arcpy.AddMessage("**** Step 2 ****")
# refresh the view
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()

arcpy.AddMessage("**** OK now were Done ****")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is a new feature in version 10.1, to my knowledge, until version 10, labels are **not** imported with layer symblology. There is even an [idea on ArcGIS ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008D0UAAU) with over 600 votes requesting this feature.

All is not lost as this can be easily done programatically with ArcObject. (not sure about python but I doubt it since python is more focused on geoprocessing) [I posted the code on ArcGIS forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/12764-Is-there-a-way-of-Importing-Label-Styles-as-you-do-Symbology) a while back.

I have since made it to an ArcGIS add-in and if there is enough interest i will add it to the resource center for public download.

Comment: Thanks @Jakib further reading has indicated that labels are not imported with layer symbology.  It would be great to have your add-in available, I'm sure many people would use it.

Comment: @user6784 - you can now download the tool [HERE](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dbb7be9d2c1c491e8c1a067ffd58aea8)

Comment: Hi @Jakib - I tried to access the tool but it's unfortunately not accessible to me.  ESRI has indicated its most likely because:  1) its not shared with me or 2) It's only accessible to the owner of the item or members of a particular group.  Im not sure how to resolve sharing issues on the site.

Comment: @user6784 -  oops, sorry. Try now. Forgot to share it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an extra step, Step1b:

---

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env


## Create parameters for modelbuilder user specified fields.
symbolize_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)
symbol_lyrFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)


arcpy.AddMessage("**** Step 1 ****")
#  apply symbology
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (symbolize_layer, symbol_lyrFile)

arcpy.AddMessage("**** Step 1b ****")
# Load up the source layer file
labelLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(symbol_lyrFile)

#Find the target layer in the map
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current") #Finds the current open map the script its running in
mapLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, symbolize_layer)[0]  #Finds the layer in the map, with the same name as "symbolize_layer"

#Copy the label info from the source to the map layer
mapLyr.labelClasses = labelLyr.labelClasses

arcpy.AddMessage("**** Step 2 ****")
# refresh the view
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()

arcpy.AddMessage("**** OK now were Done ****")
```